# Is this query correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, olap

The question is:- For the Star Model write an OLAP query that retrieves the quantity, the total income and discount 
with respect to each `city`, `type of furniture` and `month`.

This is what I have done and want to know is this correct

```
SELECT Quantity, Income, Discount, City, Type, Month

FROM Sales, Customer, Furniture, Time

WHERE Count(quantity,income,discount)

GROUP BY City, Type, Month;
```

Comment: If it works that means it is correct. Now, beware of downvotes. Xb

Comment: No !! problem on this line FROM Sales, Customer, Furniture and Time

Comment: I have never seen "AND" instead of the last comma. Is there any SQL dialect that allows this?

Comment: What are thoses "and" everywhere ?

Comment: seems like you are speeking query, not executing.

Comment: get rid of all the `and` statements to start with and you will need to properly join your tables together, look to see what is common in each of them. here is a search link to joins https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+do+table+join+in+sql&kp=1

Comment: i am still wondering is this Where clause correct? without any condition...

Comment: no, ith work ceyyoola..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misisng to do the JOIN of the tables.

You probably want to JOIN your tables.

```
Sales, Customer, Furniture and Time
```

Also try to remove the AND from your queries like

```
SELECT Quantity, Income, Discount, City, Type , Month
```

Comment: thanks this is just revision for exams and haven't learnt joining tables. So going to have a look at that.